# How to detect when Alamofire request is null?

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am using `Alamofire` to do my requests of my API on my `Swift` application and it works well but I also want to detect when the JSON response is equals to `null`.

I have tried comparing the response to `nil` and `NSNull` but none of those worked for me. I also have tried using `JSON.empty` but it also does not seem to work. Further, I have created a `default` option on my `switch` application trying to catch the options that are not `success` or `failure`.

Actually I have only maintained the `JSON.empty` option but it never enters on else statement.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
Alamofire.request(encodedUrl!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

   switch(response.result) {
       case .success(_):
          if let JSON = response.result.value as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
              if JSON.isEmpty == false{
                  //Here the code if the request returns data
              }else{
                  //Here I wanted to use the code if null is retrieved
              }
          }else{
              //The JSON cannot be converted
          }
          break

       case .failure(_):
          //Failure 
          break
   } 
}
```

How can I handle `null` responses on `Alamofire`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to return null response from api? returning empty response would be much better? like { response:[ ] }

Comment: @BehranKankul I mean that sometimes the API returns the `null` value and I need to be that value because it is also used by other applications. I only want that, for example, if the response is `null`, detect it and show a message to the user that the data that he has enter into the application is wrong or do not have information linked to it.

Comment: have your server return a status code of notFound or unprocessableEntity and then in your response you can check for the response code. If it is one of those you can display the message to the user that there is an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you code, it'll hit the `// The JSON cannot be converted` since `null` can't be casted to `[[String: AnyObject]]`.

Comment: Thank you! I think it is the only one section that I did not tried. Now I can handle it properly.